# How to bump specific git submodules?

Tags: git, github

I need to bump the submodules of a repository fairly often.  Some of my submodules use the branch `master` and some use `development`.  Right now I only know how to bump the versions properly with `git submodule foreach git pull origin BRANCHNAME`.  This will then fail and exit when I get to a branch that uses the opposite branch.  For example if I ran this with master I would get the following error causing the command to exit.

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master
Stopping at 'submodules-dir/repo-that-uses-development-branch'; script 
returned non-zero status.
```

Is there a way to either `git submodule` and only enter a single branch, so that I could pull down the branch changes one at a time? Or is there a way to filter out the branch name so that `git submodule foreach git pull origin` will only pull the branch that is currently being used for each submodule.

Answer (score 0):

Each submodule is an ordinary repository.  What's special is that it's normally in *detached HEAD* mode, i.e., not on any branch.

You can, however, [record a branch name for each submodule in that submodule's superproject](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html):

> `-b`, `--branch`
>
> Branch of repository to add as submodule. The name of the branch is
>   recorded as `submodule.<name>.branch` in `.gitmodules` for `update --remote`. A special value of . is used to indicate that the name
>   of the branch in the submodule should be the same name as the
>   current branch in the current repository.

You can then run `git submodule update --remote`:

> This option is only valid for the update command. Instead of using the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch. The remote used is branch’s remote (`branch.<name>.remote`), defaulting to `origin`. The remote branch used defaults to `master`, but the branch name may be overridden by setting the `submodule.<name>.branch` option in either `.gitmodules` or `.git/config` (with `.git/config` taking precedence).

(Aside: this means that if you `git config` the specific branch in the superproject, that overrides the default configuration saved in the `.gitmodules` file.  The `.gitmodules` file, since it is an ordinary version-controlled file, gets carried around in the superproject and exists on any fresh clone, while the `.git/config` settings are specific to your current superproject clone.)

> This works for any of the supported update procedures (`--checkout`, `--rebase`, etc.). The only change is the source of the target SHA-1. For example ... [snip]

(for further details and examples, see [the linked documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html)).